# Twitter Bootstrap isn't working with less.js

Tags: javascript, css, less, twitter-bootstrap

I have broken it down to it simplest form but still cannot find out why this is not working. All files resolve and the imports in Bootstrap are loaded yet, the styles aren't loaded.

bootstrap 1.4.0
less 1.1.3

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ahhhhhh...</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/less/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.less">
        <script src="/less/less-1.1.3.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>WTF!!!</h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

I made a simple style.less which works fine! Am I missing something glaringly obvious ?

Update:

style.less as requested by Todd :

```
@primary_color: green;

h1 {
    color: @primary_color;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your style.less?

Comment: @Todd updated the post. The style.less works fine though.

Comment: does it show the loaded/rendered stylesheet within the console?

Comment: sorry if i don't understand, but you see the less files converted to css files and the response contains something like `h1 { color: green; }` but yet you don't see the h1 element green?

Comment: When I test using style.less the h1 turns green. But when I replace style.less for bootstrap.less no styles are applied. I can see all the imports loading in the console, but no styles are applied.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I am NOT accessing the site with file:// -- I can verify the files are getting loaded in Chrome, so it isn't a path issue either.

Comment: Btw, have you tried ensuring that less.env is set to "development"? If it's not in development mode you won't be able to see the error message if you're getting a parse error. Just add something like this `<script type="text/javascript">less = {env:"development"};</script>` before you load the less.js script.

Answer (score 6):

**Update 3/5/2012**: The Bootstrap guys have fixed this problem in version 2.0.2 of Bootstrap (not yet released). See [this commit](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/c900d72857e5c3865abe9502ad7d255e84f1af0e).

The underlying bug is that the present version of less.js doesn't allow you to use a variable for for the url() value directly (e.g. `url(@iconWhiteSpritePath)`) -- instead you have to use string interpolation (e.g. `url("@{iconWhiteSpritePath}")`), which accomplishes the same thing. The bootstrap guys just updated their syntax to take this quirk into account.

**Original Answer**

I ran into the exact problem today and figured out the cause of it. Since your stack is a few versions before mine (I'm using Bootstrap 2.0 and less.js 1.2.2) I can't be sure it's the same issue, but it's possibly related.

Anyhow, the problem for me was that Twitter Bootstrap is defining some variables:

```
@iconSpritePath:          "../img/glyphicons-halflings.png";
@iconWhiteSpritePath:     "../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";
```

And then using them directly in the url() value for a background-image in sprites.less:

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-image: url(@iconSpritePath);
  background-position: 14px 14px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  .ie7-restore-right-whitespace();
}
.icon-white {
  background-image: url(@iconWhiteSpritePath);
```

}

Per the discussion in [this Github issue](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/190) that's causing a major problem. When less.js chokes on this value, the whole compilation fails.

The good news is there is a fix in that issue, provided by csnover. Just change this line in tree.URL:

```
    if (typeof(window) !== 'undefined' && !/^(?:https?:\/\/|file:\/\/|data:|\/)/.test(val.value) && paths.length > 0) {
```

to

```
    if (typeof(window) !== 'undefined' && typeof(val.value) !== 'undefined' && !/^(?:https?:\/\/|file:\/\/|data:|\/)/.test(val.value) && paths.length > 0) {
```

and you should be set. In other words, we just ensure that val.value is set so that that charAt() doesn't choke on an undefined.

Hopefully this fix will be committed to the project soon and Bootstrap will work with less.js in the browser environment out of the box.

Comment: This worked for me, but take note that this only works for the full version of less.js (available here: https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js), not the version you download from their website.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing this locally, make sure that the browser is using the correct protocol. It should display **http:** in the address bar, not **file:**.

On my Windows 7 machine using Chrome (with a XAMPP setup), I was having the same CSS problem using less.js with Bootstrap when accessing the .html file at:

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/index.html
```

However, it did render properly via http at:

```
http://localhost/index.html
```

Not certain why, but I imagine that less.js relies on HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1):

for me worked

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-image: url(../img/glyphicons-halflings.png);
  background-position: 14px 14px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  .ie7-restore-right-whitespace();
}
.icon-white {
  background-image: url(../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png);
}
```

so replace

```
url(@iconSpritePath);
```

with

```
url(../img/glyphicons-halflings.png);
```

on less.js v1.2.1 and Bootstrap v2.0.1

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue. Your solution works for me. thanks!

Comment: @Abe be careful, it doesn't work that way - use the new solution

Answer (score 0):

Is it the problem with your file structure? 
`/less/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.less` will point to the root of your domain regardless of your html file.

If you are hosting with apache and you have the following project structure:

```
www/
    your project/
        less/
        index.html
    another project/
    others/
```

When you access index.html from `http://localhost`, it will look up the `less` file from the **domain root** which is `www/`. Thus as no `less` folder is under this root directory, it will returned as 404 (not found).

So, the solution is to use relative url for your less files. If you have the above structure, remove the '/' and use `less/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.less` instead.

Comment: unfortunately this is not the problem. The app is on a virtual host and all css/less are relitive to the root of the domian. All files are resolving correctly, even to the extent that the import less files were getting loaded.